# spring-security-core:2.0-RC5 is giving error

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am working with **Grails 2.4.2**. Previously I worked with **Grails 2.1.1** and **Spring Security 1.2.7.3**. There it works fine with me. But when I have installed plugin **spring-security-core:2.0-RC5** in **Grails 2.4.2** it is giving this error:

```
Compilation error: startup failed:
D:\projects\FreightSystem\grails-app\conf\Config.groovy: 127: unable to resolve class grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType
 @ line 127, column 1.
   import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType
```

Can anyone please help me on this please? Here is my `Config.groovy` below :

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.Users'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.UsersRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'com.Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                ['permitAll'],
    '/index':           ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':       ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':       ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':        ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':       ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':    ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':  ['permitAll']
]

import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType

grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.Requestmap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType
```

But not

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType
```

(Remove the `s` from the `plugin`. Package is changed)

**Update**

Like @BurtBeckwith commented, it's mentioned in the migration doc. See **Package changes** in https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/newInV2.html

Comment: This is explained in [the docs](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/)